# Possible to output image from wgpu-rs app to Syphon?

Tags: rust, webgpu, wgpu-rs, syphon

I want to share a live texture from application written in Rust with wgpu-rs via Syphon to other apps. I did it multiple times with OpenFrameworks or Cinder. Since I switched to Rust and WGPU (to achieve better performance and Web compatibility in my app) I thought there must be some crate to achieve this.

I tried to find anything on the Internet to get started with this, and I found almost nothing... Not a single attempt to build a crate to use Syphon framework, no bindings.

Any ideas? Are WGPU textures supported anyhow to share them to other apps?

EDIT: I found one Rust app using Syphon here:
https://github.com/edeetee/render-graph/tree/main

Will examine how the author is using it. But I don't have experience in linking with 3rd party libs in Rust. Will appreciate any help.

Thanks, Teo